# Keep a permanent connection (same LAN) in the background, without using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, httpurlconnection

I need to keep an open connection in the background, even when the app is not running. It's not possible to use GCM because the connection will be in the same LAN as the server, and the device may not have a working Internet connection. 
The connection will be some kind of local Push, so the device will just get some short relevant data from time to time (in addition to the keep-alive messages).

My use case is quite specific so I can consider that the battery is not an issue. I may show a huge red warning saying that enabling the feature will drain the battery, or just disable it if the device is not charging.

On the other hand, is quite important that the process with the connection is not "randomly" killed by Android.

I thought about implementing this with a service, but I would like to hear opinions from someone else. Maybe there is a better way to do it, considering the constraints mentioned before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "even when the app is not running"

That means that your app is not running, and it doesn't have a process. Without using a third part app (such as the GCM service) that awakes your app, nothing can reach you.

You can, however, have a service that remains active and keeps a connection to a server (say, for instance, an XMPP server) to receive notifications and wake up this or that activity.

You can also do that in a separate application.

You can add robustness with a regular watchdog started by the alarm manager, for example.